# Drawing handler in NSImage -init doesn't work (Swift)

Tags: custom-controls, swift, nsimage

everybody!

I want to set image for button in awakeFromNib NSButton subclass method. 
In interface builder i set button class to my custom class. When i put drawing code in overriding drawRect method, drawing works well.

Why drawing handler doesn't work in this code

```
import Cocoa

@IBDesignable class PreviousTrackButton: NSButton {

    @IBInspectable var dx: CGFloat = 10
    @IBInspectable var dy: CGFloat = 10

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        var imageframe = NSInsetRect(self.bounds, dx, dy)

        let buttonImage = NSImage(size: imageframe.size, flipped: false, drawingHandler: {imageframe in

        NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()

        var fillColor = NSColor.whiteColor()

        println("000") // log does not in consol. 

        let point1 = NSPoint(x: NSMinX(imageframe), y: NSMidY(imageframe))
        let point2 = NSPoint(x: NSMidX(imageframe), y: NSMaxY(imageframe))
        let point3 = NSPoint(x: NSMidX(imageframe), y: NSMidY(imageframe))
        let point4 = NSPoint(x: NSMaxX(imageframe), y: NSMaxY(imageframe))
        let point5 = NSPoint(x: NSMaxX(imageframe), y: NSMinY(imageframe))
        let point6 = NSPoint(x: NSMidX(imageframe), y: NSMinY(imageframe))

        let path = NSBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(point1)
        path.lineToPoint(point2)
        path.lineToPoint(point3)
        path.lineToPoint(point4)
        path.lineToPoint(point5)
        path.lineToPoint(point3)
        path.lineToPoint(point6)
        path.lineToPoint(point1)
        path.closePath()
        fillColor.setFill()
        path.fill()

        NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()

        return true
            })
        self.image = buttonImage
        println("buttonImage")  // buttonImage not nil and have an appropriate size

    }

}
```

println("000") log does not appear in consol. Drawing handler does not invoke.
What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder Designable components do not call `init` or `awakeFromNib`, instead your code should be located in `layoutSubviews` and if you do put it there, it should work.

Comment: Subclasses of NSView does not have "layoutSubviews" method. Yes, in my case live rendering does not work, but i speak about only drawing handler now. Only this piece of code does not invoke. As you may see buttonImage instance not nil.